# What is the difference between the "is" keyword and "=="?

Tags: python, keyword, difference

What is the difference between the `is` keyword and the `==` operator in Python? Why would a programmer need to use one over the other depending on the situation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum, so we can't really go back and forth with you on questions. General confusion like " I have tried researching it but I couldn't seem to wrap my head around it." is hard to address, because we don't have any way to know **why** you're struggling with the concept, and we don't know **what** you found from your research, or **how** to make it easier for you to understand. The topic is also very frequently asked about. Unfortunately all we can really do is link you back to the existing explanation.

Comment: Please look at the answers there, and consider using the comments on an answer to ask for clarification if it still doesn't make sense. Alternately, consider asking on an actual discussion forum, such as Reddit or Quora.

Answer (score 0):

The == operator compares the value or equality of two objects, whereas the Python is operator checks whether two variables point to the same object in memory.

Comment: "whereas the Python is operator checks whether two variables point to the same object in memory" well, it checks whether *two objects are identical*. It really doesn't have anything to do with variables per se